# show line breaks in HTML textbox without showing HTML Tags when selecting data from database

Tags: php, html

I have this PHP/HTML Code:

```
<textarea name="cc_contacts"><?php
    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from tickets_extra_emails where ticketnumber = :ticketnumber ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':ticketnumber' => $_GET["seq"]));
    $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($records as $cc_contacts) {
        echo $cc_contacts["email_address"].'<br />';
    }
    ?></textarea>
```

it shows results from a table in a HTML textarea but i want it to show each returned row on its own line but not show the HMTL tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a line break using the newline escape sequence "\n".

```
echo $cc_contacts["email_address"]."\n";
```

Comment: Double quotes the escape sequence. echo "\n"